# Make value in a column equals to 1 if it is greater than 1 in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my sql.

I have divided the values in  `count` column with the 99th quartile of the column. and I got this result.

```
id  count
1    0.3
2    0.5
3    0.7
4    0.9
5    1.3
6    0.1
7    3.2
```

the code for calculating the 99th quartile which I used is :

```
 SELECT
 CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    GROUP_CONCAT(count ORDER BY count SEPARATOR ','),
   ',', 100/100 * COUNT(*) + 1), ',', -1) AS DECIMAL) AS `95th Per`
 FROM table_name;
```

and then I did:

```
select id, (count/(SELECT       
       CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
       GROUP_CONCAT(count ORDER BY count SEPARATOR ',')
        ,',', 100/100 * COUNT(*) + 1), ',', -1)
        AS DECIMAL) AS `95th Per` FROM table_name) as count1 
from table_name.
```

what challange I am facing now is

I want to `make count of the column's = 1 whenever the count is greater than 1`,
in my case for `id=5 and 7`

is there any way to tweak my query and get the desired output.
Thanks in advance.

[The code for calcluation of the quartile was found on this site](http://web.performancerasta.com/metrics-tips-calculating-95th-99th-or-any-percentile-with-single-mysql-query/)

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the query in another select similar to

```
Select 
   Id, 
   Case when count > 1 then 1 else count end as count
From (
    // place original query here
) t
```

Then you can manipulate the outer query easier to check for the count.  My case syntax may be a bit off but you get the idea.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?